# The difference between Baire 2 and 'effectively Baire 2'

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, lo.logic

In short: Baire 2 functions are often assumed to be given by a double sequence of continuous functions, thought this is not the exact definition.  Does one need the Axiom of Choice (or related) to connect these two definitions?

Longer version:  we are working over the real numbers. As is well-known, Baire 0 functions are the continuous ones, while Baire $n+1$ functions are the pointwise limits of Baire $n$ functions.

I call a function $f$ from reals to reals *effectively Baire 2* in case it is the double limit of a double sequence $(f_{n,m})_{n, m \in \mathbb{N}}$, i.e. for all reals $x$, we have
$$
(\forall \epsilon>0)(\exists n'\in \mathbb{N})(\forall n> n')(\exists m'\in \mathbb{N})(\forall m>m')( |f_{m,n}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon). \qquad (*)
$$
As pointed out by Baire himself already, Baire 2 functions can be *represented* by effectively Baire 2 functions, though Baire did not use the latter terminology.

The notion (*) is essentially the definition of Baire 2 used in reverse mathematics/second-order arithmetic.

My question is then whether one needs the Axiom of Choice (or related) to show that for a general Baire 2 function, there is a double sequence satisfying (*).

Comment: I wouldn't be too surprised if the answer is positive, but then again, it might be that AC comes into play only for Baire 3, or Baire $\omega$. These things can be finicky.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's easy to get a negative result for Baire 3. The indicator function of any countable union of countable sets is Baire 3, so if $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of countable sets, not all such functions will be codable by a real.

Comment: @ElliotGlazer that doesn't quite work. For example, if the countable union of countable sets is all of $\mathbb{R}$ then the indicator function *is* effectively Baire class 3 so there's no contradiction there. However, using the effective perfect set theorem you can get a contradiction if you have a countable union of countable sets whose cardinality is neither countable nor continuum.

Comment: @PatrickLutz: [Related](https://mathoverflow.net/q/86621/7206).

Comment: @PatrickLutz If $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of countable sets then every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is also a countable union of countable sets. My point is that there is then $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})|$ many functions in Baire class 3 so they can't all be coded by a real.

Comment: @ElliotGlazer You're right; I misunderstood what you meant by "coded by a real" in your first comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's provable in ZF that every Baire-2 function is effectively Baire-2. It suffices to prove the following:

(ZF) There is an explicit function which maps each Baire-1 function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to a sequence of rational polynomials that pointwise converge to it.

The first step is to construct a sequence of reals $\langle r_n \rangle$ such that each $r_n$ codes a rational-valued function $f_n$ such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \le \frac{1}{n}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}.$ We'll construct $r_1,$ which immediately generalizes to other $n.$

Let $U_k$ enumerate the basic open sets. We use transfinite recursion to define a descending sequence of closed sets $\langle C_{\alpha}: \alpha<\omega_1 \rangle$:

1. $C_0=\mathbb{R},$
2. $C_{\alpha+1}=C_{\alpha} \setminus \bigcup \{U_k: \forall x, y \in C_{\alpha} \cap U_k (|f(x)-f(y)|\le 1)\},$
3. For limit $\alpha,$ $C_{\alpha}=\cap_{\xi<\alpha} C_{\xi}.$

If $C_{\alpha} \neq \emptyset,$ then $f \restriction_{C_{\alpha}}$ is continuous at some $x \in C_{\alpha}$ by Baire's Characterization Theorem. Then $x \not \in C_{\alpha+1},$ so $C_{\alpha+1} \subsetneq C_{\alpha}.$ Define a surjective partial map $g: \omega \rightharpoonup\beta = \{\alpha: C_{\alpha} \neq \emptyset\}$ by sending $k$ to the greatest $\alpha$ such that $U_k \cap C_{\alpha} \neq \emptyset,$ and a well-founded partial ordering $(\omega, \prec)$ by $i \prec j$ if $g(i) < g(j).$ Define $h: \text{dom}(g) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ by $h(k)=\lfloor \sup_{U_k \cap C_{g(k)}} f \rfloor.$

Define $f_1: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ as follows: for given $x,$ let $j=\min\{k<\omega: x \in U_k \wedge \forall \alpha (x \in C_{\alpha} \leftrightarrow U_k \cap C_{\alpha} \neq \emptyset)\}.$ Set $f_1(x) = h(j).$

Let $r_1$ be a real which encodes $(\omega, \prec)$ and $h.$ From $(\omega, \prec),$ one can determine the sequence $\langle C_{\alpha}\rangle$ and hence $g.$ Thus, $f_1$ can be determined from $r_1.$ This completes the construction of $r_1$ (and hence all $r_n$).

Let $r$ encode $\langle r_n \rangle$ (and thus $f$). By Shoenfield absoluteness relativized to $r,$ we have in $L[r]$ that $r$ encodes a Baire-1 function $\hat{f}.$ Enumerate the rational polynomials by $\langle q_n \rangle.$ A Stone-Weierstrass argument shows that there is $\langle n_k \rangle$ such that $\langle q_{n_k} \rangle$ converges pointwise to $\hat{f}$ in $L[r].$ Let $\langle n_k \rangle$ be the $L[r]$-least such sequence. Applying Shoenfield absoluteness upwards relative to a real encoding $(r, \langle n_k \rangle),$ we see in $V$ that $\langle q_{n_k} \rangle$ converges pointwise to the Baire-1 function coded by $r,$ namely $f.$ This completes the construction.

Some additional remarks: The above construction can be carried out in $Z_2.$ I don't know enough about subsystems of analysis to say more with confidence. By analyzing how much of $L[r]$ is really needed in the above, you can probably get this down to $\Pi^1_1-CA_0.$

As I showed in the comments, it is not provable in ZF that every Baire-3 function is effectively Baire-3, since if $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of countable sets, then every indicator function is Baire-3.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer! You mention that your construction can be carried out in $Z_2$.  How do you assume the Baire 1 function is given in the language of second-order arithmetic?

Comment: @SamSanders In the language of $Z_2,$ you can consider the equivalence relation of $r_1 \sim r_2$ if both reals code sequences of continuous functions which converge to the same output at each $x.$ Then the construction given provides canonical representatives of each equivalence class.

Comment: In Kleene's S1-S9 computability theory, the operation  **on input a function $f$ of bounded variation, output a sequence of continuous functions that pointwise converges to $f$** cannot be done with comprehension functionals less than Kleene's $\exists^3$, which implies full $Z_2$.  This shows a big difference between computing with second-order codes and third-order objects.  Hence, one should be careful with claims about $\Pi_1^1$-comprehension etc.  See here for details: https://academic.oup.com/logcom/article-abstract/32/8/1747/6833330

Comment: What I'm proposing might be doable in $\Pi^1_1-CA_0$ is showing that the formula defined in this construction sends each pointwise convergence sequence of continuous functions to the canonical sequence of rational polynomials with same pointwise limit. This is a single sentence, so it can only use a finite fragment of $Z_2.$ What would require full $Z_2$ is the theorem scheme which provides every formula which defines the graph of a Baire-1 function a formula defining its canonical rational polynomial sequence.

Comment: Certainly one would need full $Z_2$ to prove the scheme assigning every definable class coding a pointwise convergent sequence of graphs of Baire-1 functions to a formula defining a double sequence of polynomials which effectively represents the limit Baire-2 function.

Comment: I am not saying that $\exists^3$, which does imply $Z_2$, is required: the former is just the weakest comprehension functional that computes (S1-S9) the operation **on input a function $f$ of bounded variation, output a sequence of continuous functions that pointwise converges to $f$.**  And an honest question: why do we not compute (S1-S9) with third-order functions, while we do (Turing) compute with "definable classes coding a pointwise convergent sequence of graphs of Baire-1 functions"?  Even if S1-S9 seems complicated, the coding is too, and similar coding has to be done each time.